# ActionView::Template::Error on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

I'm learning ror and currently following a tutorial to build a todo app. After updating the new.js.erb file I get the error below. It seems to be a "simple" syntax error but I just can't see what the problem actually is?

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms

ActionView::Template::Error (/todo/app/views/tasks/_task_form.html.haml:3: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
haml_temp =  simple_form_for_task, class: 'clearfix' do |f|
                                     ^
/todo/app/views/tasks/_task_form.html.haml:3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end
haml_temp =  simple_form_for_task, class: 'clearfix' do |f|
                                                   ^
/todo/app/views/tasks/_task_form.html.haml:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input):
    1: .modal-header
    2:     %h1 New Task
    3: = simple_form_for_task, class: 'clearfix' do |f|
    4:     .modal-body
    5:         = f.input :title
    6:         = f.input :note
  app/views/tasks/new.js.erb:2:in `_app_views_tasks_new_js_erb___4248753827628901371_70187720231200'


  Rendered /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (12.5ms)
```

Any pointers?

Comment: what is `simple_form_for_task` ?

Comment: The form rendered when the button "new task" is clicked. There's also a gemfile called simple_form

Comment: this doesnt answer my question, is this a method?

Comment: I'm a newbie following a tutorial, so can't answer that...yet. Here's the link for the tutorial if it helps: http://arubystory.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/tutorial-creating-simple-todo.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace with:

```
= simple_form_for task, class: 'clearfix' do |f|
```

`simple_form_for_task` seems to be a typo

Comment: It's not that. I tried. The ActionView::Template::Error remains

Comment: maybe but it should be slightly different, what is it now?

Comment: Indeed! I get     ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):

Comment: @user291 That means rails doesn't know task. Did you pass the locals: {task: @task} to the render method?

Comment: @Chai Yes, here's my partial:   `code` m = $('#modal');
    m.html('<%= j(render partial: 'task_form', locals: {task: @task}) %>');
    m.modal('show');

Comment: ok, make sure @task is being populated in your controller, because I think somehow it is nil :)